# I am using kali linux installing mysql. I am a high school student and don't know anything about it. I am getting this error

Tags: linux, mysql, kali-linux, dependencies

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-client-10.6 : Conflicts: virtual-mysql-client
 mariadb-client-core-10.6 : Conflicts: virtual-mysql-client-core
 mariadb-server-core-10.6 : Conflicts: virtual-mysql-server-core
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try `apt update`. However Kali is not for beginners. Almost any other Gnu/Linux would be better. All tools provided by Kali are available in the others. Kali is optimised of expert use.

Comment: Please review https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5361/52365

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us what installation of Kali linux you are using, I've just downloaded the 64bit Virtual Box build from [here](https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-virtual-machines) and MySQL is already installed. Please also tell us what commands you are running to install mysql as the error doesn't tell us the specific package name. If you're following a set of instructions you may have run commands before this, include these too they will help.

Comment: Try running:   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove  to see if that starts updating again. Yes, Kali is not for computing beginners.  Posted from my Kali 2022.3 machine.

Comment: https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/